# Matplotlib quiver plot with arrowheads on both sides

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible in matplotlib to generate a quiver plot with arrowheads on both sides of the arrows and if so how (without the obvious workaround of over plotting two sets of arrows).

Comment: I'm definitely not asking anyone to write code for me :) In fact, if there is no easy solution I intend to spend some time to try and extend quiver and submit patches upstream. Just want to know if a solution already exists (perhaps some little known kwarg). Posting my code is not extremely useful since it is just a call to quiver ''quiver(X, Y, U, V)'' as in the documentation.

Comment: I consider myself suitable told :) unfortunately I don't think it's possible as the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py) seems to say "Quiver plots an arrow in the
direction of the vector..." which would suggest it's only in the direction of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create two arrows pointing in opposite directions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', proj_type = 'ortho')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(-2, 2)

v_location = [0, 0, 0]
v = [1, 1, 0]

v_temp = np.concatenate([np.array(v_location), np.array(v)])
v_q = ax.quiver(*v_temp, color='black', arrow_length_ratio=0.2)

v_temp = np.concatenate([np.array(v_location), -np.array(v)])
v_q = ax.quiver(*v_temp, color='black', arrow_length_ratio=0.2)
```

[image]